# Debian package dependencies, installing specific version, not the latest

Tags: dependencies, package, debian, apt-get

So I have a Debian package I have made in my private repo and I want to install a specific version.

the package has a common lib dependency and I want to install the matching version of that package. `apt-get` is insisting on installing the lastest version of the dependency and not the version the package is dependent on.

You can see the output of the command here:

```
cmcc@cmcc-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/repo$ sudo apt-get install my_program=57.0.93
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 my_program : Depends: my_program-common (= 57.0.93) but 57.3.102 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply install the versioned commmon-package as well:

```
aptitude install my_program=57.0.93 my_program-common=57.0.93
```

Note: in general `aptitude` does a much better job for resolving dependencies than `apt-get`. usage is very similar so it's easy to switch.

### UPDATE

If you can live with an interactive process, the easiest way is probably to let `aptitude` give you a number of suggestion and choose the one that downgrades the packages. e.g.:

```
# aptitude install my_program=57.0.93-1
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  my_program{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 180 kB of archives. After unpacking 12.3 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 my_program : Depends: my_program-common (= 57.0.93-1) but 57.3.102-1 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:              
1)     my_program-common                                  
2)     my_program

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
3)     my_program recommends my_program-foo      


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     my_program-common [57.3.102-1 (now, unstable) -> 57.0.93-1 (stable)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

### Note on package-versions

It seems that your package has a version like `57.0.93`.
Such a versioning scheme is explicitley forbidden for `non-native` packages, e.g. check the [DebianMentorsFAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_native_Debian_package_and_a_non-native_package.3F).

You really should create versions like `57.3.102-1` (that is `<upstreamversion>-<pkgversion>`), even if `<pkgversion>` is always "1", due to your way of creating the package.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really do that because there are many different dependencies also which are not the same version as my_program. I would really prefer a solution in which the package manages its own dependencies. I have also thought about using the preinstall script to manage it, which I may have to do.

Comment: @Ciarán, i updated the answer by added an example of how to interactively use `aptitude` to allow a downgrade with dependencies

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution that didn't involve `aptitude`, since I don't install/use that tool and it turns out you can do this easily in regular `apt`.

First, make sure that `apt` knows about the version you want to install. You can do this with:

```
apt show <package_name> -a
```

If the version you want is listed, you can install it with:

```
apt install <package_name>=<version_string>
```

If you are downgrading the package, `apt` will warn you that the package will be downgraded and will prompt you to confirm. The reason for this is that Debian does not typically test or support package downgrades. **Here be dragons, only downgrade a package if you know exactly what you are doing and why.**

If you need to automate this somehow (e.g. with Ansible), use this:

```
apt-get -y --allow-downgrades install <package_name>=<version_string>
```

Comment: That's explicitly what the question says _doesn't work_.  He's not trying to specify a fixed version for his target package, he's having problems with a dependency of that package.